# Is civicrm-buildkit safe to use in production?

Tags: drupal, installation, best-practice, security, civicrm-buildkit

Background: I am recreating our CiviCRM installation on top of Drupal inside a Docker container. After a significant amount of research, I have decided to incorporate the best parts of [civicrm-docker](https://github.com/djcf/civicrm-docker) and the official [Drupal](https://hub.docker.com/_/drupal/) Docker container. However, before I progress too far down this road, some questions came up.

Q1: Is it sensical to run a production site that has been built using civicrm-buildkit?

Q2: What is the update procedure for a civicrm-buildkit build?

Q3: Should Drush be used instead of civicrm-buildkit?

Q4: (open ended) Does anyone have experience they would like to share?

I will keep an eye on this thread, but if anyone would like to chat realtime, I can also be found in IRC.

Thanks!

Comment: Re: drush vs civicrm-buildkit: under the hood, buildkit does use Drush for Drupal. Other hosting models could be Aegirproject.org, for example (for site/civi farms).

Comment: Djcf here. Glad you found my work useful. Rebasing off of the official drupal container seems like an inherently good idea. How did you get on in the end? Would you care to share your docker build scripts?

Comment: Yeap! It is on my [GitHub](https://github.com/altsalt/civicrm-docker), however, there are some local changes that I haven't pushed yet which fix a couple of serious bugs with the current version. Aka, don't try to run the update script.

Answer (score 2):

Buildkit is not *designed* for production use but I can't think of any reason it *can't* be used that way. As your second question suggests, the upgrade procedure will indeed be different. Steps for upgrading on a buildkit install would be:

1. Backup your database
2. Do a `git checkout tagname && git pull` for all 3 git repos (civicrm-core, civicrm-packages & civicrm-yourcms).
3. Run `setup.sh` with the correct arguments to regenerate code and download dependencies.
4. Run the upgrader (can do this from the command line as well)

You'll probably want to create a little script to do this for you.